# Different currencies not working in custom store views

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In the Default Store View that is created in fresh Magento 2 installation, the currency switcher works, but only for EUR and USD. If I add British Pound or other currency to allowed currencies then it doesn't show up in currency switcher.
If I switch to other store view in store switcher (I mad English and German store views), there are no currency switchers and both use the same currency. 
I have set Default Display Currency and Allowed Currencies to British Pound on English store view. EUR on German store view.

I tried to do this in backend and via setup script.

```
public function setDefaultCurrencies()
{
    $this->_config->saveConfig('currency/options/base', 'EUR', 'default', 0);
    $this->_config->saveConfig('currency/options/default', 'EUR', 'default', 0);
    $this->_config->saveConfig('currency/options/allow', 'EUR,GBP', 'default', 0);
}

public function setStoreViewCurrencies()
{
    $stores = $this->_storeManager->getStores(true, false);

    foreach ($stores as $store) {
        $storeId = $store->getId();

        if ($store->getCode() == 'en') {
            $this->_config->saveConfig('currency/options/allow', 'GBP', 'stores', $storeId);
            $this->_config->saveConfig('currency/options/default', 'GBP', 'stores', $storeId);
        }

        if ($store->getCode() == 'de') {
            $this->_config->saveConfig('currency/options/allow', 'EUR', 'stores', $storeId);
            $this->_config->saveConfig('currency/options/default', 'EUR', 'stores', $storeId);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: are you talking about one store or different stores, I mean different stores different currency ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing all these change you have to set the currency conversion rate.

```
Go to Admin -> Store -> Currency Rates
```

And set the currency conversion rates and save it.

After that Flush all your cache, and it will work properly.

Comment: It worked. Is there a way to do it programmatically in InstallData/UpgradeData script?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the default and allowed currencies per store view.

In terms of the system configuration of the Magento admin:

```
Go to the System > Configuration menu.
Go to the General > Currency Setup tab.
Switch to the configuration scope corresponding to the store view for which you want to change the settings.
In the Currency Options group, change the values for Default Display Currency and/or Allowed currencies (after unchecking Use websites), and press Save Config.
```

Comment: I already did that but it's showing the same currency for both views. I added screenshots to my question.

Comment: Hope this will help u - http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-setup-multiple-currency-shop/

Answer (score 0):

Please select British Pound Sterling for GBP